# pygame.mixer sound not playing when script run from command line

Tags: boot, audio

For the project I'm working on I have a python script that accepts some serial input and plays sounds depending on the input. I have the script set up and it works just fine when I run it from within the GUI. If I log out of the GUI and try to run the script from the command line though the script executes just fine but my sounds don't play. I just get a momentary static click. I can tell the script is running because I have it printing debug code and the print's work just fine.

I want this script to execute when the Raspberry Pi is turned on so per this [Running a Python script at startup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4123/running-a-python-script-at-startup) I was going to add a line to /etc/rc.local to run the script.

If there is some reason the sounds simply won't play until the GUI starts up how would I set it up to load the GUI and then execute the script on startup without any user input?

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm having the same problem:
if I name the file "02.wav" I get a very light click (the file is in the current working directory).
If I name the full file path I get a louder click - but still no sound..!

Comment: I'm glad u asked this question because I have the same problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was file path naming. If I have the command line test to the root directory it doesn't work but if I "cd Desktop/containingFolder" then the sounds play. I'll play with how I have the files set up in the python script so it will work.