# Can't update /etc/rc.local

Tags: boot, debian

I'm trying to set up a script to run on startup and I found this quesiton: [Running a Python script at startup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4123/running-a-python-script-at-startup)

I tried adding the script to my rc.local but I can't save the file. Neither can I create another copy somewhere else and overwrite it. I keep getting permission denied.

I should note that I'm doing this from the GUI and I don't know much about debian. How do I get the file to let me add the line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to run your text editor (Leafpad, I assume) as the super user (aka `root`).

In LXTerminal, type `sudo leafpad` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will prompt you for your password; after you type it in, Leafpad will start and you will be able to overwrite `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: 2020 update: now `sudo mousepad filePath` should be used