# Autostart a program at boot up?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-4, tkinter

I want to autostart a Python script that starts a Tkinter GUI at boot up.

The working terminal command to start the script is  `python3 /home/pi/Documents/slincam/slincam_menu.py`.

I added this command to `/etc/rc.local`, but the program doesn't show up at boot up. Strangely when I type `sudo /etc/rc.local` in the terminal, the program starts.

Please, does someone know a solution for this?

Comment: There are hundreds of similar questions. Answers warn **NOT** to use `/etc/rc.local`. To compound the issue you **CAN NOT** start a GUI program on boot, using **ANY** method - because there is NO Desktop until login.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a Python script at startup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4123/running-a-python-script-at-startup)

Comment: @Milliways Ok, but is there any way to autostart a GUI-program after the desktop loaded?

Comment: @Neldela look at systemd services

Comment: Add a line to `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` to autostart your GUI.

Comment: @Dougie I've tried adding ```@lxterminal -e "sudo python3 /home/pi/test.py"``` but it did't work

Comment: @Neldela I believe there is with LXDE autostart (but I have never done this) you will find some links, but many of these need to be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: YOU DON'T NEED SUDO. You probably don't need lxterminal to run a python program.

Comment: @Dougie I've also tried it with  ```python3 /filepath``` but it didn't work. Can you please tell me the correct way to to this?

Answer (score 1):

A **systemd** Unit file could do it. Try this:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit slincam_menu.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Slincam Menu
After=graphical.target

[Service]
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/slincam/slincam_menu.py

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Enable the new service and reboot:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable slincam_menu.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

Check with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status slincam_menu.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally use crontab.. You may add your command to crontab in the following steps.

1. `sudo crontab - e`
2. Open using your favourite text editor
3. At the bottom add the line:
   `@reboot python3 /home/pi/Documents/slincam/slincam_menu.py`

Before doing so, please ensure file permissions.

Comment: crontab is no good at all for a GUI program. It runs the @reboot lines before the GUI is active.